# Algorithm for animating elements running across a scene

Tags: algorithm, animation, language-agnostic

I'm not sure if the title is right but...

I want to animate (with html + canvas + javascript) a section of a road with a given density/flow/speed configuration. For that, I need to have a "source" of vehicles in one end, and a "sink" in the other end. Then, a certain parameter would determine how many vehicles per time unit are created, and their (constant) speed. Then, I guess I should have a "clock" loop, to increment the position of the vehicles at a given frame-rate. Preferrably, a user could change some values in a form, and the running animation would update accordingly.

The end result should be a (much more sophisticated, hopefully) variation of this (sorry for the blinking):

[image]

Actually this is a very common problem, there are thousands of screen-savers that use this effect, most notably the "star field", which has parameters for star generation and star movement. So, I believe there must be some "design pattern", or more widespread form (maybe even a name) for this algoritm. What would solve my problem would be some example or tutorial on how to achieve this with common control flows (loops, counters, ifs).

Any idea is much appreciated!

Comment: Most likely there is an equation for the speed of the car at time t. Have you found an equation to model that behavior? If so then its fairly simple afterwards. All you would have todo is place the car at different starting position and run the equation on each car for the next position at delta-t, then animate the car at the next position in delta-t time

Comment: @user814628 I plan to use a constant speed. So, each car instance would have a constant speed, and its position increment would derive from that. My main concern is how to test for the creation and destruction of each vehicle, specially considering a multi-lane environment, and that not every tick of the clock would generate new vehicles.

Comment: What are your conditions for a destroying a vehicle? Passed a certain distance from a control point? Or maybe after its not visible in the screen...? Its up to you. Similarly what are your conditions to create a new vehicle? Should you create one when a vehicle is destroyed? Or until it reaches a max-cap number...? This all has todo with specification, to which you haven't specified

Comment: @user814628 You are right. I'll edit and include my main parameters as soon as I have some spare time, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of your question, this doesn't seem an algorithm question, more like programming advice. I have a game which needs exactly this (for monsters not cars), this is what I did. It is in a sort of .Net psuedocode but similar stuff exists in other environments.

If you are running an animation by hand, you essentially need a "game-loop".

```
while (noinput):
    timenow = getsystemtime();  
    timedelta = timenow - timeprevious;  
    update_object_positions(timedelta);  
    draw_stuff_to_screen();
    timeprevious = timenow;
    noinput = check_for_input()
```

The `update_object_positions(timedelta)` moves everything along `timedelta`, which is how long since this loop last executed. It will run flat-out redrawing every timedelta. If you want it to run at a constant speed, say once every 20 mS, you can stick in a `thread.sleep(20-timedelta)` to pad out the time to 20mS.

Returning to your question. I had a car class that included its speed, lane, type etc as well as the time it appears. I had a finite number of "cars" so these were pre-generated. I held these in a list which I sorted by the time they appeared. Then in the `update_object_position(time)` routine, I saw if the next car had a start time before the current time, and if so I popped cars off the list until the first (next) car had a start time in the future.

You want (I guess) an infinite number of cars. This requires only a slight variation. Generate the first car for each lane, record its start time. When you call `update_object_position()`, if you start a car, find the next car for that lane and its time and make that the next car. If you have patterns that you want to repeat, generate the whole pattern in one go into a list, and then generate a new pattern when that list is emptied. This would also work well in terms of letting users specify variable pattern flows.

Finally, have you looked at what happens in real traffic flows as the volume mounts? Random small braking activities cause cars behind to slightly over-react, and as the slight over-reactions accumulate it turns into cars completely stopping a kilometre back up the road. Its quite strange, and so might be a great effect in your wallpaper/screensaver whatever as well as being a proper simulation.

Comment: That was pretty useful. I have made some progress on my own, but I have interest in implementing your suggestions, specially the separation between `update_positions` and `draw_everything`, since they are different concerns. Also, the "rules" to create a new car in a lane should in my case obviously be dependent on the position of the last-entered car on that lane. When I get my final result I'll post an answer for future reference. Thanks!